# Prove that $\mathcal{B}$ is a basis for $\mathcal{L}(V , W)$

Tags: vector-spaces

Let $V$ and $W$ two vector spaces on a field $K$ and let ${\{{\phi}_i\}}_{i = 1}^n$ and ${\{w_j\}}_{j = 1}^m$ be two basis for $V^*$ and $W$ respectively. Defining, for each $(\phi , w) \in V^* \times W$,
$$
\begin{array}{llccl}
{\Psi}_{(\phi , w)} & : & V & \to & W
\\
& & v & \mapsto & \phi(v) w\mbox{,}
\end{array}
$$
is $\mathcal{B} = {\{{\Psi}_{({\phi}_i , w_j)}\}}_{(i , j) \in \{1 , \ldots , n\} \times \{1 , \ldots , m\}}$ a basis for the vector space $\mathcal{L}(V , W)$ formed by the linear maps between $V$ y $W$? Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $T\colon V \to W$ linear. Assume $(v_1,\ldots,v_n)$ is the basis of $V$ dual to $(\phi_1,\ldots,\phi_n)$. For each $v \in V$, we have $v= \sum_{j=1}^n \phi_j(v)v_i$, by definition of dual basis. Then $$T(v) = \sum_{j=1}^n \phi_j(v) T(v_j) = \sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j=1}^n \phi_j(v)a_{ij}w_i,$$where $[T]_{(v_i),(w_j)} = (a_{ij})$ is the matrix of $T$ with respect to these bases. Well, this writes as $$T(v) = \sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij} \Psi_{(\phi_j ,w_i)}(v),$$so $$T = \sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij} \Psi_{(\phi_j,w_i)}$$and we conclude that $(\Psi_{(\phi_i,w_j)})_{(i,j) \in \{1,\ldots,n\}\times \{1,\ldots,m\}}$ is a spanning set for ${\rm Lin}(V,W)$. If you already know that $\dim {\rm Lin}(V,W) = nm$, we're done.

Otherwise, you have to check for linear independence directly. One does this as follows: Assume that $$\sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij} \Psi_{(\phi_j,w_i)} = 0.$$We must check that $a_{ij} = 0$ for all possibilities of $i$ and $j$. Evaluate the above expression in $v_k$: $$0 
 =\sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij} \phi_j(v_k)w_i = \sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij}\delta_{jk}w_i = \sum_{i=1}^m a_{ik}w_i,$$and linearly independence of $(w_i)_{i=1}^m$ gives $a_{ik} = 0$. But $k$ was also arbitrary, so we're done.

Comment: Because $W$ is a vector space? I'm not sure I get your point. If you take a vector in $W$ ($w$) and multiplies it by a number ($\phi(v)$), the result is in $W$.

Comment: By definition $V^* = {\rm Lin}(V,\Bbb R)$, so $\phi(v) \in \Bbb R$.

Comment: Oh wait, I thought $\phi\colon V\to V$, but it's $\phi\colon V\to F$. My bad! I have removed the comment.

Comment: Thank you very much! Can't I use the standar basis for $\mathcal{L}(V , W)$ to show faster that $\mathcal{B}$ is a basis? For instance, if
$$
v = \sum_{k = 1}^n {\lambda}_k v_k\mbox{,}
$$
so, defining ${\{f_{i j}\}}_{(i , j) \in \{1 , \ldots , n\} \times \{1 , \ldots , m\}}$ as the standard basis for $\mathcal{L}(V , W)$, then
$$
f_{i j}(v) = {\lambda}_i w_j
$$
and ${\Psi}_{({\phi}_i , w_j)}(v) = {\mu}_i w_j$, where
$$
{\mu}_i = \sum_{k = 1}^n {\lambda}_k {\phi}_i(v_k)\mbox{.}
$$

Comment: @jose In your notation, $\lambda_k = \phi_k(v)$, so that $f_{ij} = \Psi_{(\phi_i,w_j)}$. The basis of your question **is** the standard one.

Comment: Also, $\phi_i(v_k) = \delta_{ik}$, and so $\mu_i = \lambda_i$. Nothing new under the sun.

Comment: Oh my god! I can see now it perfectly. Thank you by your apportation.